# How to create datetime string in soapui using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

Hi I am using SoapUI for testing web services. I need to create a customer record with email address and password. Create customer record service contains emailid and password, when I click the run(submit request) button in create customer record in SoapUI, I should get the emailid  appended with current time of creation and any password.

How to do this with groovy?

Answer (score 41):

There are two common cases of inserting dynamic dateTime value in soapUI using [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy):

1. Insert formatted timestamp value. Use SimpleDateFormat in this case:

   `${=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").format(new Date())}`
2. Format timestamp as xsd:dateTime value. Use DatatypeFactory to create instance of newXMLGregorianCalendar:

   `${=javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(GregorianCalendar.getInstance())}`

I think that the first case works for you. Insert the code in your request and adjust timestamp format for your needs. BTW, it also works in responses for mock servers.

Comment: This worked for me to insert a timestamp `${=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSXXX").format(new Date())}`

Comment: How to escape the `"` in a soap String?

Comment: This worked but how do I set the next date in the above script?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a quick solution without pulling in jars that may ease the pain of Date manipulation like Apache Commons, or 
[joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Two line mode to compare dates (Ex: before / after times):

```
def startDate = new Date() 
println(startDate.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss SSS"))
```

Or one liner mode:

```
println(new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss SSS"))
```

If you doing heavy any heavy date manipulation I'd go with some of the above API's.  I don't think out of box Groovy has advanced date comparisons yet.

Answer (score 3):

The comments are using pure `Groovy` which `SoapUI` doesn't use some of the common syntax like `println` - instead it takes `log.info`.

```
today = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd")
log.info today
```